# Search by name but save by ID

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-orm

I have an auto-completing text field that pulls from a database of names (separated first/last but combined for auto-complete) and stores the selected names into an array. I am wondering is it possible to use the stored names and convert the names to the associated ID's in the array. If it is possible, how would I go about implementing that code.

(note: This is part of a dynamic text box field)

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <button class="add_field_button">Add More students</button>
   <div><g:textField name="student" value="${fieldTripInstance?.student}" class="autocomplete"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a hidden field populated when your text field changes.

```
<input type="hidden" name="studentID">
```

Assuming that you get your names via an async HTTP request, and considering that you don't specify any client code, something like this :

```
var students = [];  // array of { id, name, ... }

$(function () {
  bindAutocomplete();  // bind autocomplete on DOM ready
                       // auto complete will populate students array

  $('input[name="student"]').on('change', function () {
    var name = $(this).val();

    // find student id from array of known students, or reset value if unknown
    $('input[name="studentID"]').val(students.reduce(function (id, student) {
      // TODO : perhaps use custom comparator to ignore case, 
      //        accented chars, spaces, etc...
      return student.name === name ? student.id : id;
    }, '');
  });
});
```